# How do you combine two arrays in such a way that the two are equally distributed?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

It is way easier to give an example than to explain it with words.
Starting with 2 arrays:

{a,a,a,a,a,a,a} and {**b**,**b**,**b**}

I would like the output to be:

{a,a,**b**,a,a,**b**,a,a,**b**,a}

With a little help I found the following:

```
    let result = [];
    let ratio = array1.length / array2.length;
    let pushA = 0;
    while (array2.length >0) {
        pushA+= ratio;
        while (pushA >= 1){
            result.push(array1.pop());
            pushA--;
        }
        result.push(array2.pop());

    }

    return result;
```

Comment: Your example isn't clear enough. If you have `{a,a,a,a}` and `{b}`, do you expect `{a,a,b,a,a}` or `{a,a,a,a,b}`?

Comment: Have you checked this code for different sizes of arrays?

Comment: The code should work for different sizes, but would result in {a,a,a,a,b} or {b,b,b,a,b} depending on the order you put them in.

Richard's {a,a,b,a,a} would be optimal but I have no idea how to reach that.

Comment: Bresenham algorithm was intended especially to distribute steps by both coordinates evenly. And does this work well. Under the hood it is self-regulated priority queue.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly non-traditional way:

Use simplest implementation of [Bresenham algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) for segment with coordinates `(0,0) - (A.Length, B.Length)`

When x is incremented - insert "a", when y - insert "b"  (in general case - use next index from corresponding array)

Comment: Thanks! It sounds logical, but can you maybe write a version that uses two arrays?

Comment: What's unclear with modifying algorithm? ` for x from x0 to x1` - after that insert a into array; `y = y + 1` - after that insert b; and remove `plot(x,y)`

Answer (score 0):

For simple application, you may find size of both arrays. For example suppose size of fist array is **M** and size of second array is **N**. Also suppose **M>=N** ( If not you may interchange both arrays ).

Now, you may easily find total elements of First array to be inserted before inserting one element from Second array , which is equal to: **M/N** ( **= K**,say ).

So, while merging, you may insert K elements from First array then one element from Second array and so on untill elements exists in both arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot, done!

        `let result = [];
        let ratio = array1.length / array2.length;
        let pushA = 0;
        while (array2.length <0) {
            pushA+= ratio;
            while (pushA >= 1){
                result.push(array1.pop());
                pushA--;
            }
            result.push(array2.pop());

        }
        return result;`

Does this sound legit?

Comment: The conditions used in while loop need some changes, otherwise everything is okay.

Comment: This solution was intended for simple application as mentioned above, otherwise, we should take into consideration of (M%N) values specially in every iteration in such a way that leads to equal distribution.